# Exposing navigation properties for related entities in a Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

What is the recommended way to get to the related entities of parent entity using ASPNET WebAPI? If I have an an Album entity which has a collection of Song entities,does it make sense to
return the related Songs when fetching a specific Album OR does it make sense to have a set of navigation relationships exposed so that the client can fetch those as needed(such as in OData). 
If so are there any samples that illustrate this.
I'm just looking for the best guidance here for building a Web API for a domain model.